# User import into AWS Cognito with same user ids

Tags: c#, amazon-cognito

We are switching from one identity provider to Cognito. We need to import users into cognito user pool. We need to make sure the user ids(or sub) stay the same. Cognito `AdminCreateUser(SignUp)` API doesn't seem to support it.

Is there any way I can have same user id/sub imported into cognito ?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. It's one of the hidden pitfalls of cognito.